# Flask routing function giving error - "Internal Server Error"

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, python-3.8

For some reason, I keep getting an error detected on the index.html file whenever I add url_for(). This happens whether I add the function to only index.html, only more.html, or both.

More.html seems to accept the function without any problems however.

The code works only for the second method. I cannot get the first method working as soon as a url_for() is added to the code.

app.py:

```
import datetime

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    new_year = now.month == 1 and now.day == 1
    return render_template("index.html", new_year=new_year)

@app.route('/<string:name>')
def more(name):
    name = name.capitalize()
    defaultNames = ["Albert", "Michelle", "Ivette", "Sylvia"]
    return render_template("more.html", name=name, defaultNames=defaultNames)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Python Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if new_year %}
        <h1>It's NEW year's</h1>
    {% else %}
        <h1>NOT NEW YEAR'S</h1>
    {% endif %}

    <a href="{{ url_for('more') }}">names page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

more.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>names page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>hello, {{name}}!</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for name in defaultNames %}
            <li>{{ name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Go back</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I see "Internal server error" whenever I try to run the code with the url_for() function. The second method works fine though.

Comment: Have you tried escaping single quotes in index.html? use `\'`

Comment: If you meant to write it as: <a href="{{ url_for(\'more\') }}">names page</a> This still gives the same error. No affect.

Comment: No. escape the ones in the h1 tags